# Problems with Django REST framework filtering?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have this problem while using the Django Rest Framework. I am trying to do a get request using patient id. Now, lets say I look for patientid=6, the api returns results with patientid=6 ,patientid=26 and any ids that contain the number '6'. It looks like it searches for a substring.I want to make it work such that patient id=6 returns only the patientid results with id =6

serializers.py

```
class Radiologypdfserializerdata(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Radiologypdf
        fields = (
            'patientid',
            'testinfo',
            'clinicalindication',
            'attendingdoctor',
            'patientname',
            'age',
            'mobilenumber',
            'sex',
            'email',
            'doctorsname',
            'doctorsregistrationnumber',
            'clinicname',
            'doctorstelno',
            'createdtime',
            'radiology_id',
            'created',

        )
```

api.py

```
class RadiologypdfViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the radiology class"""

    queryset = models.Radiologypdf.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Radiologypdfserializerdata
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('patientid','radiology_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`django-filter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) library for this.

Just install it with:

```
pip install django-filter
```

And use in your viewset like this:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class RadiologypdfViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for the radiology class"""

    queryset = models.Radiologypdf.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Radiologypdfserializerdata
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('patientid','radiology_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter

The search behavior may be restricted by prepending various characters to the `search_fields`.

- '^' Starts-with search.
- '=' Exact matches.
- '@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's MySQL backend.)
- '$' Regex search.

For example change your code to the following:

```
`search_fields = ('=patientid','radiology_id')`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using SearchFilter, you can just prepend "=" to your filter fields. In this case your filter fields would be:

```
filter_fields = ('=patientid','=radiology_id')
```

According to the docs:

The search behavior may be restricted by prepending various characters to the search_fields.

- '^' Starts-with search.
- '=' Exact matches.
- '@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's PostgreSQL backend.)
- '$' Regex search.

Comment: filter_fields do not support = ^ $ ... only `search_fields` allows you to search based on these options.